# In Laravel how to show error message beside specific field?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am new to laravel. I created a simple page where a user can add a product to the database. If the product title or amount is empty; I can also show the errors. But I want to show error right beside the specific field. If the title is empty the error will show beside the title field. 
I searched and found solutions using JS and some other. But is there a way to achieve this using only laravel?

my view is like this

```
<form method="POST" action="create">
    @csrf
    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Product name"><br>
    <textarea name="description" placeholder="Description"></textarea><br>
    <input type="string" name="amount" placeholder="Price per unit"><br>
    <button type="submit">Add Product</button>
</form>
@if(count($errors))
    <ul>
        @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
    </ul>
@endif
```

and my controller is like this

```
public function store()
{   

    $this->validate(request(),[
        'title'=> 'required',
        'amount' => 'required',
    ]);

    $product = new Product;
    $product->title = request('title');
    $product->seller_id =  Auth::guard('seller')->user()->id;
    $product->description = request('description');
    $product->amount = request('amount');

    $product->save();
    return redirect('/dashboard');
}
```

Comment: there is only way to achive this by using either JS or change in html.

Comment: What Can I change in HTML?

Comment: by  placing that div after your input field.Ex. you need to take 3 divs one div with hight and width 100% ,inside div1 declare another div with hight and width 50% and place your input field in that. now declare one more div with hight and width 50% and place your error message in that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check for errors and display wherever you want like given below

```
@if ($errors->has('title')) <p style="color:red;">{{ $errors->first('title') }}</p> @endif
```

and

```
@if ($errors->has('amount')) <p style="color:red;">{{ $errors->first('amount') }}</p> @endif
```

In your code for view it can be placed as

```
    <form method="POST" action="create">
        @csrf
        <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Product name">
         @if ($errors->has('title')) <p style="color:red;">{{ $errors->first('title') }}</p> @endif <br>
        <textarea name="description" placeholder="Description"></textarea><br>
        <input type="string" name="amount" placeholder="Price per unit">
        @if ($errors->has('amount')) <p style="color:red;">{{ $errors->first('amount') }}</p> @endif <br>
        <button type="submit">Add Product</button>
    </form>
```

Additionally you can also print custom messages by returning the error text from controller as shown below

```
$customMessages = [
  'title.required'  => 'The title field is required to be filled',
  'amount.required' => 'The amount field should be completely filled'
];
$this->validate(request,[
        'title'=> 'required',
        'amount' => 'required',
    ], $customMessages);
```

Instead, if you want to show all the errors for a field you can print them as follows

```
@if ($errors->has('title')) 
   <p style="color:red;">
    @foreach ($errors->get('title') as $errormessage) 
      {{ $errormessage }}<br>
    @endforeach
   </p> 
@endif
```

Comment: It works.

I checked some more and it only gives the first error message for the respective field. If there is more than one errors for one field is there any way to show that?

Comment: I have edited the code for multiple error display. hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

All errors you can get in `$errors` array

just get them by input field name

Example:

```
<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('title') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
    <label for="titile" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Title: </label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Product name" required="required" name="title" type="text" id="title">
        {!! $errors->first('title', '<p class="help-block">:message</p>') !!}
    </div>
</div>
```

Here, `$errors->first('title')` mean its getting the first index of title errors in `$errors` array.

in your view you can do this as:

```
<form method="POST" action="create">
    @csrf
    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Product name"><br>
    {!! $errors->first('title', '<p class="help-block">:message</p>') !!} 
    <br> 
    <textarea name="description" placeholder="Description"></textarea><br>
      {!! $errors->first('description', '<p class="help-block">:message</p>') !!} 
    <br> 
    <input type="string" name="amount" placeholder="Price per unit"><br>
     {!! $errors->first('amount', '<p class="help-block">:message</p>') !!} 
    <br> 
    <button type="submit">Add Product</button>
</form>
```