# Can't set color for my strings in PHP in red

Tags: php, string, colors

I want to output my error messages in red. The code is laravel. At the moment they are held in white. How can I set for the following strings the color red:

- Bitte Startdatum eingeben
- Bitte Enddatum eingeben
- Bitte Festort angeben
- Bitte gebe eine Festinfo ein

Tried it with echo but no resolution with this.

```
        if($this->__req->isMethod('post')){
        $this->validate($this->__req, [
            'start_date'=> 'required',
            'end_date'=> 'required|after_or_equal:start_date',
            'location'=> 'required|string',
            'info'=> 'required|string',
        ],[
            'start_date.required'=> 'Bitte Startdatum eingeben', 
            'end_date.required'=> 'Bitte Enddatum eingeben',  
            'location.required'=> 'Bitte Festort angeben', 
            'info.required'=> 'Bitte gebe eine Festinfo ein',
        ]);
```

With echo the site spits a 500 server error.

I tried it so:

```
    echo '<p class="red">';
            'start_date.required'=> 'Bitte Startdatum eingeben', 
            'end_date.required'=> 'Bitte Enddatum eingeben',  
            'location.required'=> 'Bitte Festort angeben', 
            'info.required'=> 'Bitte gebe eine Festinfo ein',
    echo '</p>';
```

Comment: Is this laravel or is it yii ?

Comment: What's the 500 error your got?

Can you add the echo to your example as well?

Comment: The HTTP ERROR 500 probably means a syntax error in your script. Like a missing `}` at the end? Check the error logs.

Comment: I added the info laravel and the tried echo-code at the top.

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53332177)

Comment: Implementing the two @if statements on the beginning of my code is also an error 500.